# Repeatedly download a NetModel

Tags: neural-networks

```
NetModel["Wolfram AudioIdentify V1 Trained on AudioSet Data"]
```

I can download the NetModel, but once I quit the kernel, next time I should download the NetModel again.

After the model was downloaded, the data in the $LocalBase would be deleted.

[image]

What's the problem

[image: l]

Comment: Can you not `Export` it ?

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what yes, I can Export it, and Import it to use or manually install the model from the file.

Comment: So does that solve your problem ?

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what I'm curious about why this happen, since my other models didn't have this problem. Do you have this problem?

Comment: No, the download took a couple of seconds for me.